# How do I hide and slide a panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3 and jQuery. In the main area of my page I have a button that says "open". When a user clicks that button, I want to have a panel fly-in from the right and take up the entire height of the right margin.

At this time, I have a button and a panel, as shown in this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4fKoiI4VmM). However, I'm not sure how to initially hide it and then slide in when a user clicks the button. How can I do that? My HTML looks like this:

```
<br>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default">open
</button></div>

<div class="panel panel-default" style="width:300px;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="position:relative; top:-16px;"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>    
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInput1">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInput1">
      </div>      

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInput2">Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInput2">
      </div>

      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><button class="btn btn-primary">save</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn btn-default">cancel</button></li>        
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/OjOTIGaP/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 - I'm not sure what that jsbin is showing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to animate the showing/hiding of the panel with the button, you can do this using the jQuery animate method.

```
$('#pnl').animate({left: '10px',opacity:'1' });
```

I took your bootply example and added a little CSS and jQuery to show a working example at http://www.bootply.com/uB3YBxi9cC.

Comment: The animation wasn't my issue. It's the position and height of the panel. I'm trying to have it slide in from the right and fill the right margin of the screen.